# $\int(1/5)e^{-x/5}\,dx$ can someone help me integrate this? I keep getting negative and it should be positive

Tags: calculus

I am trying to calculate
$$\int_0^4\frac15e^{-\frac x5} \, dx$$
I use $u$ substitution

$$u = -x/5, \quad dx=-5\,du$$

$$\int(1/5)e^u(-5\,du) = -\int e^u\,du $$

$$-\int e^u \, du = -e^u $$

$$-e^u = -e^{-x/5} $$

$$= -e^{-0/5} + e^{-4/5} = -0.55$$

Comment: Please use mathjax to format your equations. I will format the first one. Check if it is right, then edit your question

Comment: And I think you just missed a sign. You need to calculate $-e^{\frac x5}$ at $x=4$ then at $x=0$. So the answer is $-e^{-4/5}-(-e^0)$

Comment: thank you for formatting! I didn't know how to do it, I will look into it for later questions sorry if it made the question confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculation is correct, but you are evaluating the limits in the wrong order. If $F$ is an antiderivative to $f$ then $\int_a^b f\,\mathrm d x = F(b)-F(a)$, but you are using $F(a)-F(b)$.

Answer (score 1):

When you do $x=-5u$ and $\mathrm dx=-5\,\mathrm du$, your integral becomes$$\int_0^{-4/5}-e^u\,\mathrm du=\int_{-4/5}^0e^u\,\mathrm du,$$which is greater than $0$.

Comment: This is correct, but it doesn't explain where the mistake happened in the original posting.